# Can a logical variable hold a NaN?

Tags: matlab

In the documentation paragraph for an internal MATLAB function (R2014a), I find the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
%   GRP2IDX treats NaNs (numeric or logical), ...
```

This phrase implies that there is an `X` such that *both* `isnan(X)` and `islogical(X)` evaluate to `true`.  This makes no sense to me.  I certainly have not been able to generate such an `X`.  For example:

```
>> X = true;
>> X(1, 1) = NaN;
NaN's cannot be converted to logicals.
```

My question: Is there some other way to interpret the line above that makes more sense?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>FWIW, the full paragraph is this:</sub>

```
%   GRP2IDX treats NaNs (numeric or logical), empty strings (char or cell array
%   of strings), or <undefined> values (categorical) in S as missing values and
%   returns NaNs in the corresponding rows of G. Neither GN nor GL include
%   entries for missing values.
```

<sub>For more content, if you have `R2014a` (or *possibly* `R2013b`), run `open table2gidx`, and scroll down in the Editor window that appears. (`grp2idx` is an internal function of `table2gidx`.)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, despite what the help may seem to imply, logical values can only be be `0` (false) or `1` (true). See `help logical` or the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html). [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) ([not a number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) is strictly a numeric datatype defined for floating-point values. It is defined under the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats) specification.

Additionally `isnumeric(NaN)` and `isfloat(NaN)` return true. And `class(NaN)` returns `'double'`. You can obtain a single precision `NaN` as it is just a floating-point value: `single(NaN)`.

Answer (score 0):

Interpret it as "NaNs (in numeric or logical arrays)". Since NaNs do not occur in logical arrays, that bit is redundant, but that doesn't make it incorrect.